# Dragula on drag the nested image doesn't stay styled

Tags: javascript, html, css, dragula

Codepen here:
http://codepen.io/jasonsawtelle/pen/jqbeXd

```
//HTML
<div id="drag_container">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ffcc00/ffffff"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/99cc00/ffffff"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/333333/ffffff"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000/ffffff"/></div>
</div>

//SCSS
//Dragula
.gu-mirror{position:fixed!important;margin:0!important;z-index:9999!important;opacity:.8;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";filter:alpha(opacity=80)}.gu-hide{display:none!important}.gu-unselectable{-webkit-user-select:none!important;-moz-user-select:none!important;-ms-user-select:none!important;user-select:none!important}.gu-transit{opacity:.2;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";filter:alpha(opacity=20)}

// Example
#drag_container{
    display: flex;
    div{
        img{
            height: 100px;
        }
    }
}

//JS
dragula([document.querySelector('#drag_container')])
```

It's a basic setup and Dragula is working, but when I drag a div, the contained, css resized image is popping to full-size during the drag event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `.gu-mirror img` to `width: 100px;` to achieve what you want. See the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONyaMB) for the result.

`.gu-mirror` is the div added by the Dragula plugin to mirror the selected element to drag somewhere else.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the right solution. First of all, redefining rules for .gu-mirror breaks single responsibility principle of the .gu-mirror clas. It's job was not to style in  a a manner specifict to the element.

One problem might be that by default, that object when dragged it's attached to body elements and it looses some styling if that style was defined based on parents (which is not the case when is's attached to body container. There is an option `mirrorContainer` where you can set so the dragged element won't loose its styling

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on `mirrorContainer`. I have tried to set this using `mirrorContainer: document.getElementsByClassName('section-list'),` but I am getting the error `o.mirrorContainer.appendChild is not a function`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('section-list')` returns a HtmlCollection

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, `document.getElementsByClassName('section-list')[0]` returns the correct element, but now it simply isn't working at all- it just defaults to appending to the body

Comment: Giving the element an ID and using `document.getElementById('section-list')` also returns the correct element but gives the error `o.mirrorContainer is null` in the console. What on earth am I doing wrong...

Comment: OK- this was my problem: https://github.com/kalcifer/ember-dragula/issues/14. Moving Dragula initialization from constructor to ngOnInit seems to have solved it.